# Can Bladesingers combine: Bladesong + Double-Bladed Scimitar + Revenant Blade feat?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, wizard, stacking, double-weapons

**Can Bladesingers combine: Bladesong + Double-Bladed Scimitar + Revenant Blade feat?**

I won't detail it heavily, but can an Elf and/or Half-Elf Wizard (Bladesinger) combine all these for enhanced benefit?

Or do the benefits not "stack/combine"?

Assume the campaign settings associated with the source material are not an issue, like if using a one-off or custom baked campaign setting (or FR/EW setting with option for other setting content).

If this combination works, this could be one wild build, if somewhat limited by its other features.

I don't ever really need to make a melee attack when I'm using Bladesong; it's mainly for the AC boost while focusing on casting (maybe I'd melee attack if in an *antimagic field* or whatever rare "can't cast because of X" situation occurs).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Yes it can be combined as long as you don't use two hands to make an attack with a weapon

*Bladesong* don't have limitations on what you are **holding** in your hands:

> ***Bladesong***:
>   Starting at 2nd level, you can invoke a secret elven magic called the Bladesong, provided that you aren't wearing medium or heavy armor or using a shield. It graces you with supernatural speed, agility, and focus.
>
> You can use a bonus action to start the Bladesong, which lasts for 1 minute. It ends early if you are incapacitated, if you don medium or heavy armor or a shield, or if you use two hands **to make an attack with a weapon**. You can also dismiss the Bladesong at any time you choose (no action required).

Nothing specifies you need to have one free hand or anything like casting a spell so as long as you don't attack with it while holding the weapon you are ok.

> ***Revenant Blade*** 
>   Prerequisite: Elf
>
> You are descended from a master of the double-blade, and some of that
>   mastery has passed on to you. You gain the following benefits:
>
> • Increase your Dexterity or Strength score by 1, to a maximum of 20.
>
> • While **wielding** a double-bladed weapon **with two hands**, you gain +1
>   AC.
>
> • A double-bladed scimitar has the finesse property when you wield it.

Only **wielding** the double-bladed weapon with 2 hands is required for Revenant Blade to proc  (the +1AC).

### Sidenotes

- **To respond to one of your comment:** *Sword burst* is legal because it has only verbal component, however any spell with a somatic
  component would make you lose the *Revenant Blade* benefit because
  you need to hold the weapon with 2 hands.
- You can put your hand back on your weapon as a free action if you are further away you could just hold the weapon in one hand (losing Revenant Blade benefits of a +1 AC for a moment) cast a spell with a somatic component, then  put your hand back on the weapon to gain Revenant Blade effect back (Bladesong would still be active and at the end of your spell you'd be fine)
- It's worth noting that a double-bladed scimitar has the Two-Handed
  property, so you can't attack with it unless you're holding it in
  both hands – @nick012000

Comment: EPIC! That was my thinking

Comment: @MaximeCuillerier: Changing from one hand to two on a weapon, or vice versa, is essentially considered a free action/non-action in terms of action economy. Related: [Can you cast spells with a Somatic component if you're holding a two-handed weapon?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/51994/33569), [Does switching between using a versatile weapon one-handed to two-handed cost anything with regards to the action economy?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/162923/33569)

Answer (score 0):

## They cannot be combined.

Bladesong ends early if you "use two hands to make an attack with a weapon" (SCAG p.142).

A double-bladed scimitar always has the two-handed property (ERFTLW p.22), which the Revenant Blade feat doesn't remove.

So while you would be able to use one, it would end your main subclass feature immediately.

Comment: only if I attack, right? as I can "hold" (wield) it with two hands. Even if i'm just running around casting "Sword burst" and other non S/M spells (if i have to go that hard-core) I'd get the pumped-up AC?

Comment: so i could combine, but not if I was melee attacking. To clean that up

Comment: Yes, but in that case you might as well just get the Dual Wielder feat (since it doesn't say anything about two weapon fighting) to get the +1 bonus anyway.

Comment: That would preclude the ability to "let go" with 1-hand and not need an action to sheath it or draw it (off-hand weapon). But the loss of AC would be the same, although you only lose your +1AC bonus WHILE casting S/M spells (like to a REACTION to your casting) as after casting the hand returns to the weapon (at no cost) to return your AC bonus

Comment: True. I was only thinking in terms of attacking for the combination, not defending. I won't change my answer though, because because it does seem like too much work to only get a +1 AC out of it. Plus, it limits you to Vand S spells.

Comment: that limit would only effect reactions to your spells, as after the spell was cast your hand is returned to weapon for the +1AC back .You only need 1 free hand & and moving your hand (in this case grip) is a free action. For +1 to max AC on a wizard there is alot i'd be willing to do (like using up an attunment), moving my hand seems a light fee.