# What's the most efficient way to add Dex to damage with an Elven Curved Blade?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, damage

I like the feat [Dervish Dance](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/dervish-dance-combat/), but it requires a scimitar. Although an [Elven Curve Blade](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/weapons/weapon-descriptions/curve-blade-elven)'s flavor text says it is "essentially a longer version of a scimitar", I don't believe that's enough of a justification for allowing that feat with this weapon.

I am building a level 1 magus and am looking ahead at feat options.  I expect I will take a high dex build and get into weapon finesse.  I definitely intend to  stay in the magus class, so I'm looking for a feat (or trait) to accomplish this goal.

Is there another way to gain a Dex bonus to attack damage via feats and the like?

Comment: Are you sure you want to deal with the [difficulties of playing a 2-handed weapon Magus](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/12581/magus-swinging-two-handed)? It removed access to their Spell Combat feature.

Comment: Thank you, and no, I completely missed that it was a 2-handed weapon. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: In that case, you'll be interested in the [Slashing Grace](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/slashing-grace-combat/) feat for other weapons you might look at. Any one-handed slashing weapon can get Dex to damage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The 'best' method (subject to specific games)

*If* your game has [Mythic](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/mythic/mythic-feats/) rules in play, [Mythic Weapon Finesse](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/mythic/mythic-feats/weapon-finesse-mythic/) does what you want at Mythic Tier 1.

### The easiest method

Elven Curve Blades come stock with Weapon Finesse compatability, and are therefore a valid choice for the [Agile](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/agile) weapon Special Ability. This does exactly what you want for a +1 enhancement bonus (minimum +2, so 8,000g).

### The cheaper method worth mentioning

[Unchained Rogue](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/unchained-classes/rogue-unchained/)s are able to select Elven Curve Blade with their [Finesse Training](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/unchained-classes/ROGUE-unchained/#TOC-Finesse-Training-Ex-) ability, which allows you to deal damage with your DEX. However, this requires a 3 level dip for a partial spellcaster.

Comment: [Useful reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Pathfinder_RPG/comments/6ge12u/when_do_you_get_dex_to_damage/dipl6fj/) about this subject.

Comment: I also found this [forum post](https://paizo.com/threads/rzs2ubfv?Elven-Curved-Blade-DEX-to-Damage#6) interesting, although not directly applicable.